# Backbone JS Click Event Handlers does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, onclick, eventhandler

I was trying to add click event handler to my backbone javascript file. But it displays an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined."
Here is the code. Any help would be appreciated.
main.js file

```
    var Song = Backbone.Model.extend();

var SongView = Backbone.Model.extend({
events: {
    "click": "onClick",
    "click .bookmark": "onClickBookmark"
},
onClick: function(){
    console.log("Listen Clicked");
},

onClickBookmark: function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log("Bookmark Clicked");
},

render: function(){
this.$el.html(this.model.get("title") + " <button>Listen</button> <button class='bookmark'> Bookmark</button>");

    return this;
}
 });

 var song = new Song({title: "sky is sdv sv"});

 var songView = new SongView({el: "#container", model: song});
 songView.render();
```

Comment: Basically this.$el is undefined in your case. Your javascript code is being executed prior to the body tag existing in your HTML document. Check if your script tags are placed before the closing body tag.

Comment: Yes, script tags are placed before closing the body tag. Thanks for your support. problem solved. @Sibasish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var SongView = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

should be

```
var SongView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

Comment: Thanks @TJ.  I can't find it before